# Youtube Data API v3: Is it possible to rate comments and replies on a video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I know this question has been asked few times in the past, like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339966/youtube-api-v3-rate-like-dislike-comment-commentthread), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35826557/how-to-rate-comment-using-youtube-v3-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469128/youtube-api-v3-cant-reply-or-rate-on-any-comment) but none of them has a definitive answer. All of these posts are at least 4 years old. So i want to know if anything has changed in the recent years that allows us to rate comments and replies on YouTube videos using [Youtube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3).